# Does java method returns copy of object or the reference of object?

Tags: java, memory-management

```
public class UnderstandingMemoryManagement1 {

  private static boolean flag = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<String> mainNameSet = getNameSet();
    mainNameSet.add("Name-6");

    Log.logInfo(getNameSet() == mainNameSet);
    Log.logInfo(getNameSet().equals(mainNameSet));
    Log.logInfo("------main() END------");
  }
  public static Set<String> getNameSet() {

    Set<String> nameSet = new TreeSet<>();
    nameSet.add("Name-1");
    nameSet.add("Name-2");
    nameSet.add("Name-3");
    nameSet.add("Name-4");

    Set<String> otherSet = nameSet;
    otherSet.add("Name-5");

    if (!flag ) {

      flag = true;
      Log.logInfo(nameSet == otherSet);
      Log.logInfo(nameSet.equals(otherSet));
      Log.logInfo("------getNameSet() END------");
    }
    return nameSet;
  }
}
```

When I run the above code why the output is like below -

```
INFO: true 
INFO: true 
INFO: ------getNameSet() END------ 
INFO: false 
INFO: false 
INFO: ------main() END------
```

***Why second time it is returning false why not true?*** As far as I know java copies the reference not the object. When it is coping the referenc not the object then it should return true for second case as well. Please explain this to me.

Answer (score 2):

The method `getNameSet()` returns a reference to a new `TreeSet` object each time it's called. You are calling this method **three** times in `main()` so you get **three different** `TreeSet` objects.

First `false` comes from comparing two different `TreeSet` object with `==` operator. These are different objects and have different reference value.

Second `false` comes from `mainNameSet.add("Name-6");` which modifies the first `TreeSet` so it's no longer equal.

Comment: Thank you @Karol Dowbecki, I overlooked the creation of new TreeSet

Answer (score 2):

You first call the `getNameSet()` method and store its result into the `mainNameSet` variable. This method contains a statement where a new `TreeSet` instance is constructed, and then you're returning this new instance:

```
Set<String> nameSet = new TreeSet<>();
...
return nameSet;
```

Then you're doing this:

```
getNameSet() == mainNameSet
```

You're **again** calling `getNameSet()`, which in turn constructs a new `TreeSet` instance and return it. **For each `getNameSet()` call, you have distinct `TreeSet` instances**.

This is why the comparison returns `false`.

---

[Java is always pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), in case of references, that means a reference passed to a method is copied.

```
void handle(Dog inputDog) {
    inputDog = new Dog("Jack");
}
```

```java
Dog myDog = new Dog("Fluffy");
handle(myDog);

// The name of the dog referenced by 'myDog' is still Fluffy.
// Upon calling the 'handle' method, a reference to my dog named Fluffy is
// copied to the local reference 'inputDog'. A new dog with the name Jack is
// constructed and stored into the 'inputDog' variable, which is distinct
// from the 'myDog' variable. So 'myDog' doesn't change at all.
```

Comment: Thank you @MCEmperor, I overlooked the creation of new TreeSet